# Finding the shortest and longest average path length in the set of all possible random graphs of a set size and set number of edges

Tags: graph-theory, topological-graph-theory

In the set of all connected, undirected and simple graphes where the numbers of vertices and edges are known, what are the shortest and longest average path length (as defined here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_path_length)?

In other words: if I were to write a code iterating through all possible connected, undirected and simple graphes of n vertices and m edges, and if, for each graph, I'd have the code compute the average path length and put this number in an array, what would be, at the end of the last iteration, the highest and lowest numbers of this array?

Comment: Can you explain what you understand by " theoretical longest average path length"

Comment: You need to be more specific. Random in what way? Graph with $n$ vertices with edges chosen with probability $p$? What do you mean by "shortest and longest average path length"? Shortest/longest possible? Average over all distinct paths in the graph?

Comment: This isn't clear, you're right. I'm trying to better formulate...

What are the shortest and longest possible average path length (APL) (Wikipedia : "the average number of steps along the shortest paths for all possible pairs of network nodes") for a random graph G of density d.

In other words, within the pool of all possible graphs of density d, what are the shortest and longest APL?

Does this make sense?

I'll edit my question if it does make better sense. Thanks!

Comment: Do you really need the "random" word? Do you want the smallest average shortest path (the shortest path between two points, averaging in all the points, you call it APL) of a graph among those with density $d$?

I still don't understand what do you understand by the longest average path. Are you considering the disconnected graphs as well?

Comment: I re-wrote my question, does it make more sense now?

Comment: @Rodolphe Your question makes much more sense now, though I don't know the answer. APL depends heavily on the structure of the particular graph, and since it is a difficult problem to enumerate all graphs on $n$ vertices and $m$ edges, my feeling is that the best you could hope for would be asymptotic results here. It's unlikely that there is a formula in $n$ and $m$ for the least/greatest possible APL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution for the least possible average path length for a connected graph on $n$ vertices and $m$ edges:

Note that the least possible average path length would be achieved in a graph $G$ for which each pair of vertices connected by an edge in $G$ have distance 1, and all other pairs of vertices have distance 2. Then the average path length would be:

$$\frac{2}{n(n-1)} \left(m + 2\left(\binom{n}{2}-m\right)\right) = 2\left(1 - \frac{m}{n(n-1)}\right)$$

But this bound is achievable. In any graph $G$ with a vertex of degree $n-1$, each pair of vertices connected by an edge are at distance 1, while all other pairs of vertices are at distance 2.